# How to detect posts changed use 'updated_time' field by facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get facebook page posts data by graph api and write to my database.
But when I design the update function, I found that the 'update_time' field is only changed while new comment added . Its not change on message edited or on comment edited.
If there have any way to detect the posts and comments edited without full compare old data in my database?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution ?